# Как составить запрос Query для Room по такому заданию?

Tags: android, android-room, room

У меня есть класс Garment c такими полями.

```
@Entity(tableName = GarmentTable.NAME)
public class Garment {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = GarmentTable.Cols.ID)
private long mId;
@ColumnInfo(name = GarmentTable.Cols.TITLE)
private String mTitle;
@ColumnInfo(name = GarmentTable.Cols.ARCHIVE)
private boolean mArchive;
@ColumnInfo(name = GarmentTable.Cols.SUMMER)
private boolean mSummer;
@ColumnInfo(name = GarmentTable.Cols.AUTUMN)
private boolean mAutumn;
@ColumnInfo(name = GarmentTable.Cols.WINTER)
private boolean mWinter;
@ColumnInfo(name = GarmentTable.Cols.SPRING)
private boolean mSpring;
```

Мне нужно настроить фильтр для `Garment` так, чтобы отображался список по выбранному фильтру.

Я пытаюсь в `Dao` сделать это так

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + GarmentTable.NAME + " WHERE :clause")
List getByClause(String clause);
```

А в коде, например, прописать

```
garments = mGarmentDao.getByClause(GarmentTable.Cols.SUMMER + " = 1 ");
```

или

```
garments = mGarmentDao.getByClause(GarmentTable.Cols.ARCHIVE + " = 0 ");
```

В итоге у меня отображается пустой список.

Если же я делаю запрос в `Dao` по определенным полям, то всё выводится корректно. Например:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + GarmentTable.NAME + " WHERE " + GarmentTable.Cols.SUMMER + " = :isSummer")
List getSummer(int isSummer);
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + GarmentTable.NAME + " WHERE " + GarmentTable.Cols.AUTUMN + " = :isAutumn")
List getAutumn(int isAutumn);
```

Почему в первом случае я получаю пустой список? Можно ли как-то создать общий запрос, вставив его в `Query` после слова `WHERE`, как в моем варианте?

Comment: Может вам лучше использовать @RawQuery? Там любой запрос можно написать. Потому что в вашем случае очень похоже что Room условие как строку подсовывает, а SQLite ее отрабатывает всегда как false, отсюда и пустой ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Потому что когда вы делаете первым способом, вы получаете следующий запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `garment` WHERE `summer = 1`
```

Очевидно это дичь :) Хорошо еще не вылетало(возможно в логкате выводилось сообщение об ошибке, а Room вместо убийства сообщения выдавал пустой ответ). Как вообще вам пришло это в голову? Какой-то извращенный способ, если честно... Если вы попробуете обрамить имя столбца сами, то лучше не станет

```
SELECT * FROM `garment` WHERE ``summer` = 1`
```

Пользуйтесь вторым вашим вариантом и все будет хорошо. Он явно куда проще в использовании.

Ну и до кучи. Чтобы описать сезон, в который актуален конкретный предмет гардероба, можно пойти двумя путями:

1. У одного предмета один сезон. Тогда в одно поле складываем число, соответствующее нужному сезону.
2. Один предмет может принадлежать нескольким сезонам. Тогда делаем
   маску. В двоичном виде записываем 1 - зима, 10 -весна, 100 - лето,
   1000 - осень. И ищем по маске

В коде это выглядит примерно так

```
const int SUMMER = 7;

@Query(select * from garment where season & :season>0)
List<Garment> getBySeason(int season);

getBySeason(SUMMER);
```